# Value not being bound to selected option in Select Menu

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a `<select>` control on my Blazor page with 3 options. I am setting `selected` on the option of "Bear". If the user does not touch the `<select>` control, I want the bound value to equal "Bear".

However, what I notice is that it only updates the bound value to what I select AFTER I update the `<select>` control. How do I force it to take the `selected` value when the `<select>` component is never touched?

```
<select @bind="selectedValue">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Bear">Bear</option>
    <option value="John Cena">John Cena</option>
</select>

<h3>Selected Value: @selectedValue</h3>

@code {

    string selectedValue;
}
```

Apprently, Blazor Fiddle exists: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/d3flx9tc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the value "Bear" to `selectedValue`, like the following:

```
string selectedValue = "Bear";
```

And remove the attribute `selected="selected"`

Now, "Bear" is selected, and the variable `selectedValue` contains the string "Bear". This is how you should initialize your elements.

Incidentally, you should use only `selected` without `="selected"`. It is meaningless. You could use `selected="DoNotSelectMe"`, and it will still work

Comment: This is a contrived example for my real project. In my project, I have a list of `<select>` controls that default to various values depending on other values. So you might have 3 selects that default to "bear", and 2 that default to "apple", and 5 that default to "john cena". I'm creating these `select` controls in a loop. I guess I could default the value like you said, but I was hoping I could save that code and just have `selected` property do it for me at time of UI rendering. Sounds like I need to flip-flop where my logic is.

Comment: Fine. You've asked a question...I've answered it. No issue. Create a new question, show what you did, and we'll try to help.

Comment: I initialized the element as you suggested and removed the `selected` attribute altogether. I didn't realize that `selected` is not needed when the variable bound to the `select` already has a value. It works perfectly and the code is much cleaner. Thanks for your help.